# Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization

I tried to run the graph cut algorithm for a slice of an MRI after converting it into PNG format. I keep encountering the following problem:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

This is even after setting `vmin` and `vmax` as follows:

```
plt.imshow(out, vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Answer (score 85):

Cast the image to `np.uint8` after scaling `[0, 255]` range will dismiss this warning. It seems like a feature in `matplotlib`, as discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9391/).

```
plt.imshow((out * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 40):

Instead of `plt.imshow(out)`, use `plt.imshow(out.astype('uint8'))`. That's it!

Answer (score 17):

If you want to show it, you can use `img/255`.

Or

```
np.array(img,np.int32)
```

The reason is that if the color intensity is a float, then [matplotlib expects](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) it to range from 0 to 1. If an int, then it expects 0 to 255. So you can either force all the numbers to int or scale them all by 1/255.

Answer (score 14):

As the warning is saying, it is clipping the data in between (0,1)....
I tried above methods the warning was gone but my images were having missing pixel values.
So I tried following steps for my numpy array Image (64, 64, 3).
Step 1: Check the min and max values of array by

```
maxValue = np.amax(Image)
minValue = np.amin(Image)
```

For my case min values of images were negative and max value positive, but all were in between about (-1, 1.5) so
Step 2: I simply clipped the data before imshow by

```
Image = np.clip(Image, 0, 1)
plt.imshow(Image)
```

Note if your pixel values are ranged something like (-84, 317) etc. Then you may use following steps

```
Image = Image/np.amax(Image)
Image = np.clip(Image, 0, 1)
plt.imshow(Image)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Pytorch based grad_cam I was getting similar errors in `show_cam_on_image` and what worked cleanly was

```
input_image = Image.open(filename)
img=np.array(input_image.resize((227,227)),np.float32)
img *= (1.0/img.max())
```

Answer (score 3):

this solved the problem:

```
plt.imshow(image..astype(np.uint8) / 255)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with you and I solved by **reversing the normalization**.

In my case I was loading the image using PIL and used torchvision transform functions.

I first used **ToTensor()** method which will scale the data into range **[0..1]** and then applied **Normalize()** method which will produce the **negative values** since we are making our data to follow **standard normal distribution**.

As the warning message says, if our data is floats we should make sure our data are in range of [0..1]. To do so, we should reverse back our data to which have had values in range of [0..1]. So I reversed the normalization and it worked.

You can take a look at this [link](https://sparrow.dev/pytorch-normalize/).

Hope this helps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

***Simply make it within this range  [0:1]***

if it is between [-1, 1] after calling the amax() and amin() then

```
img = img / 2 + 0.5
```

if it is between [0, 250]

```
img = img / 250
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.astype("uint8")`, therefore you should have something like:

```
plt.imshow(image.astype("uint8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was solved through first casting the image to a numpy array.

```
plt.imshow(image.numpy().astype("uint8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**plt.show(Image) Expect the image range to be between 0 to 1 if image dtype`float` and 0-255 if image dtype `int`**

type `image.dtype`  if it **floats** then the problem is that it's range -1 to 1, ***and you need to make the range between 0 and 1, and this is how you do it:***

```
image=(image+1)/2
```

if 'image.dtype output **int** then the problem is that values are 0 and 1 and its type is int so convert type to float

```
np.array(img,np.float32)
```

or  multiple values of image by 255 so values between 0 and 1 become between 0 and 255

```
img=img*255
```

ref https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html