# How pyplot.imshow treat image with different data types?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm currently working on GAN models and using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` to save the image in grid format.

During saving image samples generated by GANs, I realized it was still in `float32` data type when I put it into `pyplot.imshow`, different with my initial image data format (`uint8`). So for research purpose, I casted the image back into `uint8` with 0-255 value range.

When I inspect both images with `pyplot.imshow`, I'm seeing a very similar image

[image]

This is how I plot all the images

```
img = # input image for GAN
gen_img = # GAN output given 'img' as input

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 16),
                        subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})
axs = axs.flat

img = (img + 1) * 127.5
axs[0].imshow(np.reshape(img, (row, col)))
axs[0].set_title('Source')

gen_img_float = gen_img * 0.5 + 0.5
axs[1].imshow(np.reshape(gen_img_float[0], (row, col)))
axs[1].set_title('gen_img shown in [0-1] float scale')

gen_img_uint = (gen_img + 1) * 127.5 
axs[2].imshow(np.reshape(gen_img_uint[0].astype('uint8'), (row, col)))
axs[2].set_title('gen_imgs shown in [0-255] uint8 scale')

plt.show()
```

How does this resulting in similar image plot, especially when the inputs are in different datatypes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. matplotlib plots the image using a colormap where the highest value in your data is mapped to black and the lowest value to white and intermediate values correspond to shades of grey. Therefore it does not matter whether your range is [0-1] or [0-255]

Comment: @DizietAsahi is the mapping depends on data or data type? I found from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643907/clipping-input-data-to-the-valid-range-for-imshow-with-rgb-data-0-1-for-floa they have valid range for specific datatype