# Matplotlib save animaiton as video but get empty content

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, video, visualization

I am trying to make an animation with continue rotating an image, but the output video file has empty content(Only axis left), how to fix it?

```py
import math

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import scipy.misc
from scipy import ndimage

my_image="img.png"
out_file="myvideo.mp4"

class UpdateDist:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.img = mpimg.imread(my_image)
        self.ax.imshow(self.img)
        self.degree = 1


    def __call__(self, i):
        rotated_img = ndimage.rotate(img, self.degree*10)
        self.ax.imshow(rotated_img)
        self.degree += 1
        return self.ax,


plt.axis(False)
plt.grid(False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ud = UpdateDist(ax)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, ud, frames=100, interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
ani.save(out_file, fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I applied some edits to your code:

- replaced `self.degree` with `i`: `i` increases by 1 in each iteration, no need for another counter
- moved `ax.grid(False)` and `ax.axis(False)` (and added `ax.clear()`) within `__call__` method, in order to use them in each frame
- removed `blit` parameter from `FuncAnimation`
- replaced `.mp4` output file format with `.gif`
- used `imagemagik` as `writer`

Let me know if this code achieves your goal or if you need any further modifications.

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np


my_image='img.png'
out_file='myvideo.gif'


class UpdateDist:

    def __init__(self, ax, rotational_speed):
        self.ax = ax
        self.img = plt.imread(my_image)
        self.rotational_speed = rotational_speed

    def __call__(self, i):
        rotated_img = ndimage.rotate(self.img, self.rotational_speed*i, reshape=False)
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.grid(False)
        self.ax.axis(False)
        self.ax.imshow((rotated_img*255).astype(np.uint8))
        return self.ax,


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ud = UpdateDist(ax = ax, rotational_speed = 1)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, ud, frames = 91, interval = 1)
anim.save(filename = out_file, writer = 'pillow', fps = 30)
```

### Animation

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! For your code I have got the output message as `MovieWriter imagemacik unavailable; using Pillow instead.
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).` , do we need to fix it?

Comment: You can replace `imagemagik` with `pillow` for the first warning and check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643907/clipping-input-data-to-the-valid-range-for-imshow-with-rgb-data-0-1-for-floa) for the second one. In any case, I updated my code in order to avoid these warnings

Comment: Could you please check why there are heartbeat-like effects? I don't see any special APIs in your code. I want to get a smooth result like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOHRpA5ReQ0&t=75s&ab_channel=DanielE) .My input image is a circle, so I think we need to put the center of the circle in a static position.

Comment: I updated my code: now you can regulate the rotational speed (how many degrees the image is rotated between two consecutive frames) with the `rotational_speed` parameter. The lower the speed, smoother the animation. However this could led to a slow animation, so you can compensate with `fps` parameter when saving the animation.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated your code with `reshape=False` parameter to make the rotation smooth.