# Hide: "Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am printing images in a for loop using `imshow()`. However, for every iteration there is the message, `Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).`.

I don't want it to be visible as it takes up a lot of space in the output.
Is there any function to hide it or is there any way around getting to get the desired output without the message?

Comment: clip your data between 0 and 255?

Comment: How do i do that without showing the message of the data being clipped?

Comment: Is your data floats or ints?

Comment: Does [Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643907/clipping-input-data-to-the-valid-range-for-imshow-with-rgb-data-0-1-for-floa) answer your question? Searching with the error message is a good place to start on SO.

Comment: @wwii
I want to explicitly clip them instead of using imshow command
because imshow gives an output which I don't want to be visible ("Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow......")

Comment: [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html#numpy.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html#numpy.clip)